# IntelliJ IDEA 15 "Code > Generate" context menu missing "equals() and hashCode()" entry

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

In my IntelliJ IDEA 15 (build 143.382), the context menu invoked via "Code > Generate" is missing the "equals() and hashCode()" entry. How can I configure the context menu contents to bring it back?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My bad, turns out the contents are context-sensitive: I was invoking the menu from a class which didn't have any instance fields...

Comment: Sometimes, the tools are almost too smart for us... ;-)

Comment: Well, not sure if this is really "smart", I would prefer the menu item to just be disabled rather than absent...

Comment: You are right, that would be clearer. The disabled menu items could even show a tool tip explaining the situation.

Comment: Even though, if a class inherits from another class (which overwrites equals), shouldn't the subclass also override it to enable that only the instances of the subtype are equal?

Comment: @FreekdeBruijn i want to use properties instead.

Comment: Seems also to happen if your class does not have any fields but the extended class does ...